# LinearLayout Problem (2 LLayout in the same XML)

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I'm coding new XML fils for desinging an android app and I've some problem by using 2 linearLayour into the same xml...

I've "Error in a XML file: aborting build" with the following code :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/texte_firsttab"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


      <Button android:id="@+id/accessGraphe"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

  <Button android:id="@+id/accessGraphe2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="test2"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can we put two linear layout in the same xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But not two at top level.
See this example : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Comment: perfect, I've put them in an other linear layout ;-)

Thank you ! Now I will understand why the buttons want not to be showed ^^

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two top-level layouts. How would the system know how to arrange them? You need to enclose them in another layout that defines this.

I assume that the blanks in front of the `<?xml ...` tag are due to code formatting in your post and are not present in the actual layout file. That would also cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.... how would you refer to one or the other from the source code ?

If you want to have two linear layouts at the same time (one on top and one at the bottom), then you need to embed those within another layout :

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weigth="1">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/texte_firsttab"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weigth="1" >


      <Button android:id="@+id/accessGraphe"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct" />

  <Button android:id="@+id/accessGraphe2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="test2"
    android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two root-level items, which shouldn't happen (this is not specific to Android layout files, you can have only one document element in any XML file).

I wouldn't recommend wrapping the to LinearLayouts in another one, that's too complicated; and it's generally a good idea to avoid nesting layouts, see [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html) about efficient layouts.

For a TextView and two Buttons, a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) would be perfect. It's also more flexible than LLs.